# Python-based program can't find installed packages

Tags: python, package, python-cryptography

I'm trying to run a new version of a program on an old version of Raspbian OS (10 / buster) that requires the *python3-cryptography* package. The program requires at least Python 3.8 so, I had to upgrade my version of Python on the machine to 3.8.15, and then installed the *python3-cryptography* package, among other dependencies. When I try to run the program, it fails to launch with the error

> Error: at least one of ('pycryptodomex', 'cryptography') needs to be installed.

If I try to run `sudo apt-get install python3-cryptography`, it tells me it is already the newest version (2.6.1-3+deb10u2). Using `dpkg -L`, I can also see that there is a cryptography package installed at `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/` and a python3-cryptography package installed at `/usr/share/doc/python3-cryptography/`

Moreover, If I extract the specific lines of code from the program that imports cryptography and run just those lines in the Thonny Python IDE, everything works fine - no errors. I tried adding some print statements to debug the program itself and the error it throws is **No module named 'cryptography'**. It seems like the package is available in the environment that the Thonny Python IDE is running in, but not in whatever environment is used when I launch the program. My best theory is that Thonny may still be using 3.7 while the environment for the program is 3.8, or vice versa.

**Is there a way to tell which version of python (3.7 or 3.8) the *python3-cryptography* module was installed to?**
I have tried also installing cryptography using `pip3.8 install cryptography`, but this fails with errors. It's a little tough for me to parse all the lines, but one of the last lines is:

> Error: `cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src/rust/Cargo.toml --release -v --features 'pyo3/extension-module pyo3/abi3-py36' -- --crate-type cdylib` failed with code 101

**Is this an issue with Rust?**

I don't know enough about Linux to understand how to see what is available in each environment, why running the program from the terminal isn't working, or how to direct the program to the proper environment. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I just noticed that Thonny displays the version of Python its using in the lower right corner, and it is indeed 3.7.3. Is there a way to force apt-get to install python3-cryptography into Python 3.8, or to get 3.8 to look for it in the right place?